# Como guardar el id del usuario logueado en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario donde el usuario puede publicar nuevas noticias, por lo que tengo una relación entre la **tabla user** y la **tabla noticias**.
¿Como puedo guardar el ID del usuario logueado cuando el usuario publique una noticia nueva?

Controlador:

```
 public function crear(Request $request){
    // return $request->all();

    $noticiaNueva = new App\Noticia;
    $noticiaNueva->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $noticiaNueva->imagen = $request->file('imagen')->store('public');
    $noticiaNueva->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $noticiaNueva->fecha = Carbon::now();
    $noticiaNueva->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;
    $noticiaNueva->user_id = $request->user_id;

    $noticiaNueva->save();

    return back()->with('mensaje', 'Noticia agregada');
}
```

Como se puede ver, estoy recibiendo el ID por formulario, pero eso no se debe hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener el ID del usuario logueado podes hacer uso de la facade [`Auth`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) o del helper [`auth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-auth):

```php
$noticiaNueva->user_id = auth()->id();
```

Al estar usando `Request` también podes hacer:

```php
$noticiaNueva->user_id = $request->user()->id;
```

Comment: En definitiva responder desde el celular no es bueno, no te avisa si hay alguna respuesta ya publicada, elimino la mia pues es prácticamente igual y apoyo la tuya con un +1